# Set properties for specific patch in matplotlib.collections.PathCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter, z-order

I would like to set individual properties (`zorder` and `label` for example) for a specific element of a `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`. I couldn't find a way in the documentation.

Here I jot down a user case.
Let say we have the following snippet, and we'd like to change the `zorder` of the *red* ball, bringing it to the top, by using the `balls` handle, which is a `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`.

```
balls = plt.scatter([-1, 1], [0, 0], c = ['r', 'b'], s = 4e4)
plt.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])
```

[image: Overlapped balls]

Does anyone have any idea about how to tweak individual paths of a `PathCollection`?

The alternative would be using `plt.plot('o')`, which actually returns a `list` of handles. Unfortunately the `plt.plot('o')` solution won't allow me to set a different colour per ball, since they would all belong to the same chart. So a `for` loop would be required.

The drastic solution, which I bet I'll go for, since my deadline, is going of Inkscape :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it might help you.

From what I can see, the `paths` in the `PathCollection` are always plotted in the order they are created. So in your case, the `path` with the x-position of `-1` is created first, then the one with `1`.

You can switch that order after initially plotting them, by changing the `offsets`, in your case using `balls.set_offsets()`:

```
In [4]: balls = plt.scatter([-1, 1], [0, 0], c = ['r', 'b'], s = 4e4)
In [5]: plt.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])
```

This creates the following figure:[image]

```
In [42]: print balls.get_offsets()
[[-1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]

On [43]: balls.set_offsets([[1,0],[-1,0]])
```

Now, this has plotted the left-hand ball on top of the right-hand ball:

[image]

But as you can see, this has also switched the `facecolors` around (since we set the order of that in the call to `plt.scatter` as `['r','b']`. There's a solution to this, which is to also switch the `facecolors` around:

```
In [46]: balls.set_facecolors(['b','r'])
```

[image]

---

Great, so putting that all together, we can define a function to switch the offsets and facecolors of any two arbitrary `paths` in the `PathCollection`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
balls = ax.scatter([-3, -1, 1, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], c = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'm'], s = 4e4)
ax.set_xlim(-6,6)
ax.set_ylim(-6,6)

plt.savefig('balls_01.png')

def switch_scatter(pathcoll,a,b):

    # Switch offsets
    offsets = pathcoll.get_offsets()[:]
    offsets[[a,b]] = offsets[[b,a]]

    # Switch facecolors
    facecolors = pathcoll.get_facecolors()
    facecolors[[a,b]] = facecolors[[b,a]]

    # Switch sizes 
    sizes = pathcoll.get_sizes() 
    sizes[[a,b]] = sizes[[b,a]] 

    # Set the new offsets, facecolors and sizes on the PathCollection
    pathcoll.set_offsets(offsets)
    pathcoll.set_facecolors(facecolors)
    pathcoll.set_sizes(sizes)

switch_scatter(balls,2,1)

plt.savefig('balls_02.png')
```

Heres `balls_01.png`:

[image]

And here is `balls_02.png` (where we switch ball 1 and ball 2 (the blue and green balls)

[image]

---

A final note: if you have other properties varying in your scatter plot (e.g. linecolor), you will also need to switch them around in the function I defined above.

Comment: OMG! Amazing! What happened is that a small ball was hiding under a bigger one and I wanted to avoid changing the order of my data and colours, since they are used elsewhere. In line plot I did use the `zorder`, but here I was not able to handle the situation the same way. I'll use your solution, but I will try to understand your function after the deadline, although the explanation in English make totally sense. Thank you very much for watching my back!

Comment: Question: how did you find out about `offsets`? Just to understand your modus operandi.

Comment: For completenes: `# Switch sizes` `sizes = pathcoll.get_sizes()` `sizes[[a,b]] = sizes[[b,a]]` and then `pathcoll.set_sizes(sizes)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit that into the answer. I found `offsets` by just tab-completing on the `balls` collection to see what properties it had, and finding the one that looks right. If you look at `balls.properties` (I think), its a dictionary of all its properties, so you can quickly find the ones you need.

Comment: LOL, OK. I was expecting some more fancy answer, haha! NIPS 2016 deadline is in 2 hours. Let try to review this masterpiece, haha! I'm thinking to add you to the *Acknowledgements* section ;) Do you have a name, or will you be a "stackoverflow user"?

Comment: One more "bug". Before swapping, we need to check `if len(property) > 1:`, to account for the case in which one property is a scalar (*i.e.* shared across all data points). About the acknowledgement, you can find it here -> http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07678. Thank you again!

Comment: Moreover, I'm not sure about how to look at `balls.properties`. All I get is `<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x10d8a7240>`.